# html Multiple file select and queue (add/delete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

What i want to do is to be able to select multiple files using the multiple attribute on  tag but when starting to upload ( POST) each files will be uploaded individually + having the possibility to remove a file from the queue(this is what makes things even much harder, because adding files is not a problem since i can easily create another element but removing is impossible).

Now for security reasons its impossible to alter a file tag in html! so far what i have done is having a single file input and when selecting a file, a new element is created in its place so i am giving the illusion of a queue and then using jquery i upload each file individually! ( cant select multiple files at once but everything works)

I have found some flash plugins but i don't want to depend on more libraries, if it was a simple flash file no problem but most of those plugins need additional js files etc...

I would be happy to see a cross-browser solution. Again i know there are some flash plugins that can do this, but i am after a cleaner and simpler way maybe a single swf file or something ....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) does all of this, and in a single simple small swf.

Comment: Ok, uploadify seems to handle the uploading part too which i don't really want since the application does some kind of session validation/creating for each file before its uploaded. is it possible to just have uploadify selecting multiple files and add them to the DOM and stop there ?